# Managing and Maintaining too many on click jquery handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, content-security-policy

I recently have been upgrading the Phonegap to the latest version and now it forces me to follow the Chrome's **Content Security Policy** which in a way is good. But now I am forced to remove the all the **onclick** handlers in the HTML code and add them in the jquery handler some$(document).ready(function(evt){

```
$('#addRecordBtn').on('click', function(){
    alert("Adding Record");
    AddValueToDB();
});

$('#refreshBtn').on('click', function(){
    alert("Refresh Records");
    ListDBValues();
});

});
```

But as per what my app is scaled upto I feel that there will be **too many** of these handlers. Is there an example which shows maintenance of such handlers and a proper way or proper place of defining such handlers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an idea. You could make an object that stores all of the functions that also knows how to give up the function

```
var handlers = {
    getHandler: function (str) {
        return this[str];
    },
    '#addRecordBtn': function () {
        alert("Adding Record");
        AddValueToDB();
    },
    '#refreshBtn': function () {
        alert("Refresh Records");
        ListDBValues();
    } 
};
```

Then apply all of your handlers using this form.

```
$('#addRecordBtn').on('click', handlers.getHandler('#addRecordBtn'));
$('#refreshBtn').on('click', handlers.getHandler('#refreshBtn'));
```

**Optimization Time** if you want to get really fancy and you assign a unique ID to every button as convention

```
var handlers = {
    defer: function () {
        return function (){
            handlers[$(this).attr('id')](arguments);
        };
    },
    registerHandlers: function () {
        for (var key in this) {
            if (this.hasOwnProperty(key) && typeof(key) === "string") {
                $('#' + key).on('click', this.defer());
            }
        } 
    },
    'addRecordBtn': function () {
        alert("Adding Record");
        AddValueToDB();
    },
    'refreshBtn': function () {
        alert("Refresh Records");
        ListDBValues();
    } 
};
```

call it with

```
$('#addRecordBtn').on('click', handlers.defer());
$('#refreshBtn').on('click', handlers.defer());
```

or register everything automatically

```
handlers.registerHandlers();
```

[Here is a fiddle of my solution](https://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/5013/)

Comment: In doing this, I'd go one step further and give all the buttons you need a class, then *one* handler adds all the functions by ID. I.e. `$('.buttons').on('click', handlers.getHandler($(this).attr('id')));`

Comment: @ArtOfCode I was trying to think if that would work. Wouldn't this be bound to whatever object that entire line resides within. For example the window object?

Comment: Never tried it, I just came up with that! Let me have a go quickly

Comment: @ArtOfCode I got an idea I'll modify it.

Comment: Your code has a syntax error... `getHandler` is not a function

Comment: @ArtOfCode this is simmilar to what you are talking about. This dynamically binds at runtime to lookup the handler.

Comment: @ArtOfCode the fiddle unfortunately didnt show alert.

Comment: @AnkitTanna I don't think it works because `this` is not bound to the button dom element the way he is calling it. Mine works because it lets the click handler call that code so `this` is bound to the button.

Answer (score 0):

Do you look for something like this?

```
$('[data-clickhandler]').on('click', function(e) {
    var $btn = $(e.currentTarget);
    var handler = $btn.data('clickhandler');

    alert('Refresh ' + handler);
    window[handler] && window[handler](e);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Now your elements can specify their clickhandler like so:

```
<a data-clickhandler="AddValueToDB" href="">...</a>
```

Or so:

```
<span data-clickhandler="ListDBValues">...</span>
```